# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() disable network on win 7

Tags: java, jar

how i can enable/disable network with java program `.jar`

how i can use :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec()
```

is this can do

```
Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig/release");
```

thank you

Comment: i cant run command on devcon
 
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        //rt.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","start"});
        rt.exec(new String[]{"C:/1/i386/devcon -m://test find pci/*"});
        System.out.println("rt");
        //Process result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig /release");
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can help me to fix this

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("netsh", "Lan", "disabled","name=\"lan\"");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```